# Initializing color palette assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

Is there a way I can restore the standard color palette(256) after changing it's values using port 3C8h? Here is how I changed it.

```
proc copyPal
    mov si, offset palette
    mov cx, 256
    mov dx, 3C8h
    mov al, 0
    out dx, al
    inc dx
    palLoop:
    mov al, [si+2]
    shr al, 2
    out dx, al
    mov al, [si+1]
    shr al, 2
    out dx, al
    mov al, [si]
    out dx, al
    add si, 4
    loop palLoop
    ret
endp copyPal
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also `shr al, 2` for the blue component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the 256 color registers in a similar way. Just use the PEL Address Read Mode Register at 03C7h.
Next codes require that the segment registers `DS` and `ES` are equal and that the
direction flag is clear (`cld`).

```
PreservePal:
    mov di, offset Buffer768
    mov cx, 256
    mov dx, 03C7h   ; Address
    mov al, 0
    out dx, al
    mov dx, 03C9h   ; Data
  palLoop:
    in  al, dx      ; Red
    stosb
    in  al, dx      ; Green
    stosb
    in  al, dx      ; Blue
    stosb
    loop palLoop
    ret
```

For restoration, use next code:

```
RestorePal:
    mov si, offset Buffer768
    mov cx, 256
    mov dx, 03C8h   ; Address
    mov al, 0
    out dx, al
    mov dx, 03C9h   ; Data
  palLoop:
    lodsb
    out dx, al      ; Red
    lodsb
    out dx, al      ; Green
    lodsb
    out dx, al      ; Blue
    loop palLoop
    ret
```

Please note that your *palette* buffer has 1024 bytes (8 bits per byte hence your conversion factor of 4), whereas my *Buffer768* has 768 bytes (6 bits per byte hence no conversion needed).

Comment: unfortunately it did not work. What does stosb do?

Comment: @YarinB The `stosb` instruction is equivalent to the pair `mov [es:di], al` `inc di`. You can always change the code to operate in a similar fashion to your code. Also, I left out the conversion factor of 4 that you were using.

Comment: I wanted to try to just reverse the functions and the order but it did not work out. Does it make sense doing it that way?
```proc standardPalCopy
 mov si, offset standardPalette
 mov cx, 256
 mov dx, 3C7h
 mov al, 0
 out dx, al
 mov dx, 03C9h
 spalLoop:

 in al, dx
 shl al, 2
 mov [si + 2], al
 
 in al, dx
 shl al, 2
 mov [si+1], al
 
 in al, dx
 shl al, 2
 mov [si], al
 
 
 add si, 4
 loop spalLoop
 ret
endp standardPalCopy```

Comment: @YarinB The code in this comment looks fine. Your existing *copyPal* routine could be used to restore the colors provided the line `mov si, offset palette` is modified with the new buffer address *standardPalette*. Also don't forget that here the buffer must have room for 1024 bytes.